# How to add attribute values to the admin on Hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Based on fabcar-sample (v1.4) I developed an app in which I want to use attribute values for the admin and for the users. I face an issue about how to add attribute values while I enroll in the admin. I do not know if it is possible to add attribute values for the admin. In the examples that I have seen are only added from the registered users. In the fabcar sample looks like the admin is just enrolled and not registered in contrast to the users.

---

- *registerUser.js*

```js
const gateway = new Gateway();
await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'admin', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });
console.log('Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node');
// Get the CA client object from the gateway for interacting with the CA.
const ca = gateway.getClient().getCertificateAuthority();
const adminIdentity = gateway.getCurrentIdentity();
console.log('Get the CA client object from the gateway for interacting with the CA');

const aff = adminIdentity.getAffiliation();
const secret = await ca.register({ affiliation: aff, enrollmentID: username, role: 'client', attrs: [ {"name": "email", "value": "myemail@test.com", "ecert": true} ] }, adminIdentity);
const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: username, enrollmentSecret: secret, attr_reqs: [{ name: "email", optional: false }]});
```

- *enrollAdmin.js*

```js
const caInfo = ccp.certificateAuthorities[ca_info];
const caTLSCACerts = caInfo.tlsCACerts.pem;
const ca = new FabricCAServices(caInfo.url, { trustedRoots: caTLSCACerts, verify: false }, caInfo.caName);

// Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), wallet_info);
const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: username, enrollmentSecret:'adminpw'});
const identity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity(MSP, enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());
await wallet.import(username, identity);
```

- *smartcontract.go*

```
func (c *SmartContract) getEmail(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) (string, error) {
    email, ok, err := cid.GetAttributeValue(stub, "email")

    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    if !ok {
        return "", errors.New("email attribute is missing")
    }

    return email, nil
}
```

Any idea how to add attribute values on the admin while in this process in not registered the admin like the users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of the `admin` client, when the `fabric-ca-server` is executed, the value can be set in the configuration. Most of the examples work only with the ID and password by using the `-b` option. like `fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d`

---

default configuration can be changed in [`fabric-ca-server-config.yaml`](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/b89ee34ff745b76922f00049df07629baaf3fe5d/test-network/organizations/fabric-ca/org1/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml) file.

> fabric-ca-server-config.yaml link is fabric-samples v2.0, but fabric-ca has no changes(v1.4) and the configuration form is the same.

You can add `admin's attr` in this file.

---

**[EDIT] I wrote it according to the guide document, but I confirmed that it does not work. After deepdive analysis of the code, I confirmed and corrected that the regular expression did not work properly.**

`hf.Registrar.Attributes: "*"`

to

`hf.Registrar.Attributes: "email,hf.Registrar.Roles,hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles,hf.Revoker,hf.IntermediateCA,hf.GenCRL,hf.Registrar.Attributes,hf.AffiliationMgr"`

in fabric-ca-server-config.yaml

---

Here is example.

- docker-compose-ca.yaml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  ca.org1.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.4
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/<your_ca_org1_private_key>
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -d'
    volumes:
      # mounting fabric-ca-server-config.yaml file
      - ./fabric-ca-server-config.yaml:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server/fabric-ca-server-config.yaml
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.org1.example.com
```

- fabric-ca-server-config.yaml

```yaml
...
registry:
  maxenrollments: -1
  identities:
     - name: test
       pass: testpw
       type: client
       affiliation: ""
       attrs:
          # <add_your_attrs>
          email: "myemail@test.com"
          hf.Registrar.Roles: "*"
          hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles: "*"
          hf.Revoker: true
          hf.IntermediateCA: true
          hf.GenCRL: true
          hf.Registrar.Attributes: "email,hf.Registrar.Roles,hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles,hf.Revoker,hf.IntermediateCA,hf.GenCRL,hf.Registrar.Attributes,hf.AffiliationMgr"
          hf.AffiliationMgr: true
...
```

- enrollAdmin.js

```js
...
// Enroll the admin user, and import the new identity into the wallet.
// with attrs
const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: 'test', enrollmentSecret: 'testpw', 
                                     attr_reqs: [{ name: "email", optional: false }] });
const x509Identity = {
    credentials: {
        certificate: enrollment.certificate,
        privateKey: enrollment.key.toBytes(),
    },
    mspId: 'Org1MSP',
    type: 'X.509',
};
await wallet.put('admin', x509Identity);
console.log('Successfully enrolled admin user "admin" and imported it into the wallet');
...
```

```sh
node enrollAdmin.js
Successfully enrolled admin user "admin" and imported it into the wallet
```

it works!

---

[NOTE] If you don't want to touch the docker or configuration it's okay to add another admin to work.

- registerAndEnrollAdmin.js

```js
...

// Register the user, enroll the user, and import the new identity into the wallet.
const adminUser = await provider.getUserContext(adminIdentity, 'admin');

const secret = await ca.register({
    affiliation: 'org1.department1',
    enrollmentID: 'admin2',
    role: 'client',
    attrs: [ {"name": "hf.Registrar.Roles", "value": "client,orderer,peer"}, {"name": "hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles", "value": "client,orderer,peer"}, {"name": "hf.Revoker", "value": "true"},
            {"name": "email", "value": "test@example.com"}, {"name": "hf.Registrar.Attributes", "value": "email, hf.Registrar.Roles, hf.Registrar.DelegateRoles, hf.Revoker, hf.Registrar.Attributes"} ] }
, adminUser);
const enrollment = await ca.enroll({
    enrollmentID: 'admin2',
    enrollmentSecret: secret,
    attr_reqs: [{ name: "email", optional: false }]
});
...
```

then you can register users using `admin2`

Comment: thank you for your response! I agree it works but i think it works because optional field is set to true. If optional field is set to false does not work. Moreover, the admin is enrolled and imported to the wallet with the optional field to true, but afterwards the problem is in the smart contract because does not recognize the attribute email for the admin client. The post is edited and added the function of the smart contract.

Comment: I have found a problem now! I'll check

Comment: @ myeongkil kim thank you!Really useful answer!